# NestJS. Custom provider, inject can't resolve dependencies of the useFactory

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I get the following error during app start:
`Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the useFactory (?). Please verify whether [0] argument is available in the current context.`

`ConfigService` is exported and `ConfigModule` is loaded as first module. Don't know if it's my fault or it's a bug in NestJS. 
Maybe somebody could find something) Thank you.

database.providers.ts:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { SEQUELIZE_TOKEN } from './constants';
import { User } from '../users/user.entity';
import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';

export const databaseProviders = [
 {
  provide: SEQUELIZE_TOKEN,
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    const sequelize = new Sequelize({
      dialect: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: configService.databaseUser,
      password: configService.databasePassword,
      database: configService.databaseName,
      operatorsAliases: false,
      logging: false,
    });
    sequelize.addModels([User]);
    await sequelize.sync({ force: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local'
    || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test',
    });
    return sequelize;
  },
  inject: [ConfigService],
 },
];
```

Part app.module.ts:

```
@Module({
 imports: [
  ConfigModule,
  DatabaseModule,
  GraphQLModule,
  UsersModule,
 ],
 exports: [DatabaseModule],
})
```

Part config.module.ts:

```
@Module({
 providers: [
    {
        provide: ConfigService,
        useValue: new ConfigService(`./config`),
    },
 ],
 exports: [ConfigService],
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to import `ConfigModule` inside your `DatabaseModule`. The providers in Nest aren't globally scoped by default.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. Maybe add information about scope of providers to official docs (custom providers section)?

Comment: Yes, there are many custom decorators techniques available to follow. Reading out this in 2021 :).